# sending form to php with iframe

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, iframe

I am writing a form, where user can send info, and attach a file, which sends via email to certain users.

I've built a HTML form, and because I don't wanna to refresh the page I sent it via a hidden iframe.

Everything was working, until I added captcha to my form. Now I've got a problem. I store a generated string for captcha in the session on the main form page. But because the form is sending from an iframe I think PHP is creating a new session, which is empty.

Can anyone have suggest how can I connect iframe and my form page to same the session? I would like to mention, that the iframe is created dynamically by JavaScript when the user clicks to send the form.

thanks for advice!

**edit:**
my code
HTML form page:

```
<input type="text" name="name"/><br />
<input type="text" name="email"/><br />
<textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
<input type="file" name="file"/><img id="captchaimg" src="http://xxx/mailsend.php?application=xxx&image=get"/><input type="text" name="captcha"/>
<input type="button" id="send" value="send"/>
```

my JS file:

```
function sendFromIframe() {
    if ($('#hiddeniframe').length == 0) {
        var iframe = ('<iframe name="hiddeniframe" id="hiddeniframe" src="" border="0" height="0" width="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
        $("body").append(iframe);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        var form = $('#feedback');
        form.attr('target', 'hiddeniframe');
        form.attr('method', 'POST');
        form.attr('action', 'http://xxx/mailsend.php');
        form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        form.submit();
        wait4refresh();
    }, 550);
}
function wait4refresh(counter){
    var counter = counter || 0;
    var bolean = false;
    var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'http://xxx/mailsend.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'application=' + $('input[name="application"]').val() + '&issend'
    });
    request.done(function(msg){
        if (msg == 'true'){
            bolean = true;
        }
    });
    if (bolean){
        refreshCaptcha();
    }
    else if (counter > 10){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            counter++
            wait4refresh(counter);
        },500);
    }
}
function refreshCaptcha() {
    var application = $('input[name="application"]').val();
    d = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    $('#captchaimg').attr('src', 'http://xxx/mailsend.php?application=' + application + '&image=get' + '&' + d);
}
```

and the PHP file:

**i get error "connection reset by peer" when I'm trying to add my PHP code here. what can I do?**

Answer (score 0):

Couldn´t you just create a `<div id='htmlform'> </div>` and just make it visible/invisible with jquery?